# How do I run Windows vim from a function within my .bashrc?

Tags: bash, vim, cygwin

I have installed windows vim and added the following function to my .bashrc:

```
function winvim() {
    local win_vim_path='/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Vim/vim73/vim.exe'
    #local win_vim_args=`cygpath -w -a "$*"`
    "$win_vim_path"
}
```

When I type winvim I am informed that there is 'No such file or directory'. However, if I type the path explicitly in cygwin vim runs as expected.

What is wrong here?

Comment: the `\\` are going to be lost. you need to double-escape

Comment: @MarcB sure? IMHO he _dont't_ need the ` \ ` because the path is in single quotes...

Comment: but without the escapes the command will be seen as `/cygdrive/c/Program` with arguments `Files` and `(x86)/Vim/vim73/vim.exe`.

Comment: @MarcB Not if you quote the expansion of `win_vim_path`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When setting the value of `win_vim_path`, you need *either* single quotes or the backslashes to escape the spaces/parantheses, but not both.

```
local win_vim_path=/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Vim/vim73/vim.exe
```

or

```
local win_vim_path='/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Vim/vim73/vim.exe'
```

The quoted version is preferred as easier to read and type.

Answer (score 3):

From memory:

```
local win_vim_path="$(cygpath -u "$PROGRAMFILES")/Vim/vim73/vim.exe"
```